# How to remove all unwanted TreeView Branches

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, self-join

In a C# Treeview, I need to remove all branches that do not contain values in a list in the leafs.
For example, I have a list { 112, 74 }  and a Tree:
The Data Source is a self-joined table. So I can't easily remove the unwanted leafs and branches.

Root
  Branch1
    Leaf 112
    Leaf 1
  Branch2
    Leaf 74
  Branch3
    Leaf 44
    Branch4
       Leaf 99

I should end up with:
Root
  Branch1
    Leaf 112
  Branch2
    Leaf 74

Here is the code. It sort-of works.  But the TrimTree only removes the bottom level. So I need to run this function a few times to completely remove all the empty branches. VERY inefficient.

```
    void GetTree(ref TreeView tv)
    {
     DataTable dt = c.GetTable("select id, parent_id, name from tbl_self_join_tree");
        tv.DataSource = new HierarchicalDataSet(dt, "ID", "Parent_ID");
        tv.DataBind();
    }

    void TrimTree(TreeNodeCollection nodes, List<string> l)
    {
        TreeNode node = null;
        for (int ndx = nodes.Count; ndx > 0; ndx--)
        {
            node = nodes[ndx - 1];
            if (node.ChildNodes.Count  == 0 && !l.Contains(node.Value))
                nodes.Remove(node);
            else   
                TrimTree(node.ChildNodes, l);
        }
    }
```

If I can write a better SELECT query, then I won't need the TrimTree() function :D
Solving this will help a LOT!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me you can process parent nodes after processing child nodes. This way you can handle branches with all leafs deleted:

```
//DISCLAIMER: I didn't compile or test this method.
void TrimTree(TreeNodeCollection nodes, List<string> l)
{
    TreeNode node = null;
    for (int ndx = nodes.Count; ndx > 0; ndx--)
    {
        node = nodes[ndx - 1];
        TrimTree(node.ChildNodes, l);
        if (node.ChildNodes.Count  == 0 && !l.Contains(node.Value))
            nodes.Remove(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent...  I didn't think of processing parent nodes after child nodes.  This looks efficent enough so I don't need to write a etter SELECTR query for now.  Thanks again!

Comment: @EricNewman congratulations! If you think that your question is already answered then you can accept answer. Check out the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: @EricNewman I believe you should consider optimizing your database query. Manual editing of UI element looks more like a workaround for me.

Comment: Manual editing the UI elements IS a work around.  But I don't know how to even start such a query.  I can easily filter out leafs I want, but the branches will remain.

Comment: @EricNewman you can post another question targeting sql query. I can only see `tbl_self_join_tree` in your question.

Comment: I created a new thread called Part2: which will focus using a correct SELECT statement to solve this correctly.